# Where does git rebase store commit message during conflict resolution?

Tags: git-rebase

During a git rebase conflict resolution, where does git store the commit message for the commit I'm resolving conflicts for?

Sometimes when I run `git commit`, the `COMMIT_EDITMSG` will be pre-populated, other times, it won't be.

Answer (score 0):

The commit message for the commit you are resolving conflicts for is stored in this file:

```
.git/rebase-merge/message
```

First, you hit a rebase conflict.

If you stage changes, run `git commit` - then `COMMIT_EDITMSG` will be pre-populated with `.git/rebase-merge/message`.

<sub>You can even add changes to a totally unrelated file without conflicts, and git will pre-populate for you.</sub>

It will continue to pre-populate with this message until you've successfully made one commit.

After the first commit, it will no longer pre-populate with `.git/rebase-merge/message` when you run `git commit`. Undoing last commit, and redo-ing will not cause it to pre-populate again.
<sub>The file at `.git/rebase-merge/message` will still be the same at this time, however. I'm not sure why git decides to stop pre-populating with this message.</sub>

Eventually, once you stage all changes, and run `git rebase --continue`, the `COMMIT_EDITMSG` will pre-populate again with `.git/rebase-merge/message`.

<sub>I would like to understand why git no longer pre-populates your `COMMIT_EDITMSG` once you've made one commit!</sub>

Comment: Is this an answer to your question or is it another question?

Comment: It's definitely an answer. I do have a few questions interspersed, but these add important context I myself would likely want in the future. Feel free to copy what I have into your own answer which is more  focused on the information you were expecting, I'd be happy to upvote it!